# Wrong location information on log4j console

Tags: grails, log4j

I've configured my appender in Config.groovy as:

```
log4j.main = {
    includeLocation="true"

    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%l -> %m%n')
    }
    ...
```

The results from my log console are displaying all messages as if they were called from log4j code instead of my own code:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.debug(SLF4JLog.java:128) -> saproto1.importacao.TentativaImportacao : 8
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.debug(SLF4JLog.java:128) -> Processing sheet Plan1 (0)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.debug(SLF4JLog.java:128) -> saproto1.importacao.LinhaTentativaImportacao : 1751
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried a sample with just log4j and slf4j libraries but didn't face this issue. The above log messages also show up apache commons logging. Thats strange too.

Comment: Any chance I could get rid of slf4j from my grails app? It's probably beeing interpreted by log4j as the callee for all my log messages.